# SQL - Exists comparison

Tags: sql, db2, exists

I need to select rows that have one treated row for one country and there exists one untreated row for the same country. For below table I would then return row with `id = 1`.

So first I need to check if there is a row with `TREATED` status, then I have to check if there is a row with `UNTREATED` status and the same country as the one with the `TREATED` status.

```
    Table example 1
    +----+--------+--------------+
    | id | country| status       |
    +----+--------+--------------+
    | 1  | SE     | TREATED      |
    | 2  | DK     | UNTREATED    |
    | 3  | SE     | UNTREATED    |
    +----+--------+--------------+

    Result of query
    +----+--------+--------------+
    | id | country| status       |
    +----+--------+--------------+
    | 1  | SE     | TREATED      |
    +----+--------+--------------+
```

If there does not exist an untreated row or the country is not the same then we should not return anything

```
    Table example 2
    +----+--------+--------------+
    | id | country| status       |
    +----+--------+--------------+
    | 1  | SE     | TREATED      |
    | 2  | DK     | UNTREATED    |
    | 3  | US     | UNTREATED    |
    +----+--------+--------------+

    Result of query (empty)
    +----+--------+--------------+
    | id | country| status       |
    +----+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of other options:

```
select t1.id,t1.country,t1.status
    from table t1
    join table t2 on t1.country=t2.country and t2.status='UNTREATED'
    where t1.status='TREATED'


 select id,country,status
            from table t1
            where 
                 t1.status='TREATED' and
                 exists (
                      select 1 from table t2 where 
                           t2.country = t1.country and 
                           t2.status = 'UNTREATED'
                 )
```

I believe the first one, using a join, would probably perform the best.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted because it was the query that was easiest understand/read.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select country
from table
where status in ('treated', 'untreated') -- only needed if there are other statuses
group by country
having count(distinct status) = 2
```

Comment: aha, I see. Wasn't sure. You never know how permissive the rdbms you don't work with may turn out ;-)

Comment: Even if it was so shabby (I'm looking at you, mysql) I should have put it in :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country  FROM table
WHERE status IN ('treated', 'untreated')
GROUP BY country HAVING count(DISTINCT status)=2;
```

syntax may vary depending on sql, not sure about `db2`.

Comment: Great thanks both of you. But I want to return id, country and status (not only country).

Comment: Basically, you can either call whatever aggregate on those (like `min(id)`) or you can use it as a subquery. like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE country IN (SELECT *the query in the answer goes here*)`.

Comment: Thanks. What if we were to complicate things a little and add a requirement that we should only return results if it is treated by user "x" and it is untreated by user "y"?

Comment: We would probably change the condition :)